# LightGBM python package - version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found

Tags: python, gcc, pip, glibc, lightgbm

I'm trying to install and use `lightgbm` package in python, but it seems like there is a version conflict related to gcc.

After installing the package, using `pip install lightgbm`, when trying to import it, the following error appear:

```
>>>import lightgbm

OSError: /usr/company/pkgs/gcc/4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /nfs/user/.venv_notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
```

Although I have other versions of GCC installed, I'm not sure to make it use the appropriate version it needs.

```
ls /usr/company/pkgs/gcc/

10.1.0  10.3.0  11.1.0  4.7.2  4.8.1  4.9.2  5.3.0  6.2.0  6.3.0b  6.4.0  6.5.0  7.2.0  8.2.0  8.3.0  9.1.0  9.2.0
```

Couldn't find an answer for this, any thoughts?